# "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression" in latest Chrome

Tags: jquery-selectors

I've been working on my internal website for a week and got a working demo. I went to show a colleague my work on his computer and the demo didn't work at all. I tracked the problem down to the version of Chrome; he was on the latest (v21) and I was not (v20). When I upgraded to v21, the demo stopped working for me as well. It also broke in the latest Firefox (14).

I'm using the [Bootstrap Tour library](http://pushly.github.com/bootstrap-tour/) and tried jQuery 1.7.1 through 1.8.0.

What I'm specifically doing is looping through various DOM elements (some with ids, some with only classes) grabbing their CSS styles using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element). The idea is to find the dimensions of the visual element and overlay another div on top of it of the same size. It worked great until I upgraded my browsers.

The jQuery/Sizzle error I get is "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: XXXXXX" where XXXXXX is some vendor CSS extension such as '-webkit-input-placeholder' or '-moz-focus-inner'. If I remove the offending tag from the Bootstrap Tour's CSS, another error is generated for another vendor extension.  Removing these CSS tags eventually breaks Bootstrap tour.

Is there anything I can do other than tossing Bootstrap Tour and writing my own?